# Is Christ androgynous?

Tags: catholicism, christology, eastern-orthodox

What are the stances, if any, of the Eastern Orthodox and Catholic Church on whether Christ was androgynous?

Comment: Define androgynous and cite a source that claims Christ is androgynous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Androgyny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Androgyny): *the combination of masculine and feminine characteristics into an ambiguous form*.

AFAIK there are no biblical textual references that could interpret *Jesus* as androgynous, but there are several scholarly arguments for *God* being androgynous.

Since both the Orthodox and Catholic church adhere to the doctrine of the Trinity, a single God who is both three and one (triune); the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit, "one in essence and undivided", e.g. the Trinity shares one divine essence (ousia); uncreated, immaterial and eternal, any biblical reference to the nature of God is relevant as well.

From [Intertextuality in Ugarit and Israel](https://books.google.nl/books?id=gxEWKPXGOmUC) by Johannes Cornelis De Moor, Society for Old Testament Study:

[image]

From [God and Women: Woman in God's Image and Likeness](https://books.google.nl/books?id=DPByCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA110#v=onepage&q&f=false) by John D. Garr, founder and president of Hebraic Christian Global Community

[image]

Isaiah 42:14

[image]

Young's literal translation:

> I have kept silent from of old, I keep silent, I refrain myself, As a
> travailing woman I cry out, I desolate and swallow up together.

Comment: The question is whether Christ is androgynous and not whether God is androgynous. There is a nuance to the question.

Comment: Doesn't trinitarian doctrine claim that God exists as three persons, each of them having the one identical essence or nature, not merely similar natures?

Comment: But since the incarnation Christ also has a human nature.

Comment: But according to doctrine, Jesus was only human for 30 odd years, and millennia (or "billennia" for Old-Earth Creation) part of the trinity. So the nuance is negligible or at least not all-encompassing, no?

Comment: As far as I understand the term, androgynous does not infer any sexual abnormality so even while Christ was a man in flesh, he could have expressed both feminine and masculine traits equally, making him androgynous. In hind sight this questions of Christ androgynous nature seems to be an obvious and resounding yes. I was just surprised to have not found a larger number of accessible, official references.

Comment: The question asks for the position of the Eastern Orthodox and Catholic Church on this issue. You should incorporate some source that reflect their position on this subject.